# Date format issue in SSRS

Tags: vb.net, date, reporting-services

I have an issue with date format in my SSRS.  I am saving date from `DateTimePicker` to database.  From there I am taking display in my datagridview using following

```
dgv.items(0,2).value=Format(Cdate(dsSaver.tblInv.rows(0).items(0)),"dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

This displays it correctly `(04-Nov-2011)` but when I take date from the same database to my SSRS using

```
="Dated: " &Format(cdate(Fields!InvDate.Value),"dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

It displays it like `11-Apr-2011.`

I have tested all winforms fare displaying it right but all SSRS are displaying it wrong.
Please advise.

Comment: You are right, the format is the same but the problem is the same date is 11-Apr-2011 and same same is 04-Nov-2011.  Don't u see anything wrong in that?  How can the same date has two different months

Answer (score 4):

A couple of things are going on here. The date is being saved appropriately but is being displayed incorrectly due to your formatting options. This line is quite problematic:

```
="Dated: " & Format(cdate(Fields!InvDate.Value), "dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

CDate takes a value, generally a string, and converts it to a date, which you are then taking and formatting back into a string. Now, by default reports are set to have their Language property set to `English (United States)` so the CDate function is taking the string representation of the date `04-Nov-2011` to be `04/11/2011` which it is then converting, using the US format of `MM-dd-yyyy` (not the Pakistani one) into being the date `11-Apr-2011` because it thinks the month comes first.

So, you should change your Language setting of your report to `=User!Language` so that it supports whatever the user's language is and will format things appropriately. This may be enough to make your expression work.

Regardless, if `Fields!InvDate.Value` is being supplied as a date field (as it should be) there is no need for the CDate function and this should work:

```
="Dated: " & Format(Fields!InvDate.Value, "dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

There is also the [FormatDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.formatdatetime.aspx) function but unfortunately it doesn't support the format you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the RDLC options for [Formatting a Report: Format the Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627538.aspx)?